# CakePHP: Date select with reverse year order

Tags: cakephp

Currently i create a select element for date input in a view like this:

```
echo $form->input('my_field_name', array(
         'type' => 'date',
         'label' => 'my_label',
         'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
         'minYear' => date('Y'),
         'maxYear' => date('Y') + 5));
```

which has the following output in HTML (for the year select):

```
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2011">2011</option>
```

What i need is to output the years in reverse order like this:

```
<option selected="selected" value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
```

Is there any way to get this result using the `FormHelper` class of Cake and without doing anything custom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you take a look at the core test files?
Always a good idea to do that first before asking the community.

there you can find specific tests for this matter

```
$result = $this->Form->year('Model.field', 2006, 2007, array('orderYear' => 'asc'));
```

etc

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. It is helpful and quite enlightening. I am relatively new to CakePHP and i wasn't aware of the core test files. I was actually looking at the documentation for `FormHelper::input()` and there is no reference to that option there. The documentation for this option is actually found at `FormHelper::year()` entry.

Comment: interesting - if you want to can add the order stuff to the documentation yourself. all you need to do is pull the current github repo of the docs (https://github.com/cakephp/docs), modify and make a pull request to the core team.